# product of two irrational numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

if $v_{1}=\frac{1+\sqrt[3]{10}+\sqrt[3]{10^2}}{3}$ and $v_{2}=\frac{7+4\sqrt[3]{10}+\sqrt[3]{10^2}}{3}$

let $\omega_{1}=v_{1}-k$ and let $\omega_{2}=v_{2}-l$ where $k,l\in\mathbb{Z}$

How do I ''shift'' $v_{1},v_{2}$ by some integers $k,l$ so that $\omega_{1}\omega_{2}\in\mathbb{Z}$? How do we even begin to choose integers that might work? Is there a standard way?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save typing I set $\alpha={\root3\of{10}}$, so that $\alpha^3=10$.  Multiplying out and simplifying,
$$\eqalign{\omega_1\omega_2
  &=\frac{1}{9}(1+\alpha+\alpha^2-3k)(7+4\alpha+\alpha^2-3l)\cr
  &=\frac{1}{9}\bigl((57-21k-3l+9kl)+(21-12k-3l)\alpha+(12-3k-3l)\alpha^2\bigr)\ .\cr}$$
Now the numbers $1,\alpha,\alpha^2$ are linearly independent over the rationals.  So the only way this expression can be a rational number is if the coefficients of $\alpha$ and $\alpha^2$ are zero.  This gives you two equations which you can solve to find $k,l$.  If $k,l$ are not integers then your problem has no solution; but it turns out that $k=1$, $l=3$.  If you now substitute back into the above, and if $\omega_1\omega_2$ is not an integer, then again your problem has no solution; but it turns out that $\omega_1\omega_2=6$.

I'll leave you to fill in the details for yourself.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you!:)

Answer (score 1):

$$
w_1w_2 = \frac{(57-k-7l)+10^{\frac{1}{3}}(11-k-l)+10^{\frac{2}{3}}(18-k-4l)}{3}
$$

Now if the above is an integer, clearly the irrational terms must become zero and other terms in the numerator must be multiple of 3. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Cheers